# Checking table cell for an &nbsp; and coloring it

Tags: css

I asked a question about coloring an empty cell for accessibility purposes and I got a great answer that worked perfectly. Now I have found some of the empty cells actually contain the  **`&nbsp;`**. I would like to be able to check for that and colorized as well. I did this and it did not work, is it possible?

```css
table td[&nbsp;]:before {
    background-color: gold;
    content: "Cell only contains a &nbsp;";
    
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: that sounds like a javascript job :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot check the content of a tag, javascript can

here is a test example that might not cover all situation you have:

```js
// edit : best is to do it once the page is loaded 
window.onload = function() {
  let tdEmpty = document.querySelectorAll('td');
  for (i = 0; i < tdEmpty.length; i++) {
    if (tdEmpty[i].innerHTML == '&nbsp;') {
      tdEmpty[i].classList.add('empty')
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: solid 1px;
}

td {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background: gray;
}

:empty {
  background: hotpink;
}

.empty {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the very quick reply!! I will put this to good use!

Answer (score 0):

You need js to achieve that. Something like:

```js
const highlightBg = (selector, seed, color) => {
  const elements = Object.values(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  const elementsToHighlight = elements.filter(
    (element) => element.innerHTML.includes(seed),
  );
  
  elementsToHighlight.forEach((element) => element.style.backgroundColor = color);
}

document.querySelector('#highlightButton').addEventListener(
  'click',
  () => highlightBg('td', '&nbsp', 'gold'),
);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cel A1</td>
      <td>Cel A2</td>
      <td>Cel&nbsp;A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cel B1</td>
      <td>Cel&nbsp;B2</td>
      <td>Cel B3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cel&nbsp;C1</td>
      <td>Cel C2</td>
      <td>Cel C3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<hr>

<button id="highlightButton">Highlight</button>
```

Comment: Thank you as well for the quick reply, it will indeed come in handy!!